# Is it compliant with Google and Youtube policies that an app downloads captions from youtube videos using Python package: Youtube Transcript API?

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, closed-captions

I'm working on a mobile app that provides translated captions on Youtube videos, using a Python package: Youtube Transcript API [link](https://pypi.org/project/youtube-transcript-api/) to download captions from youtube videos, beyond what youtube api officially offers as methods.

I need to know if this is compliant with Google and Youtube policies. If not, is there any compliant alternative method I should use?

Below some apps that do pretty much the same thing :
[ccTube](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kigate.cctube)
[zTranslate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=asia.zsoft.subtranslate)
[Lingvotube](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mmt.translingua)